# React-Native Real-Time Firebase How to find all child components(all references)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, iot

I want to get all child components without writing anything.

I want to get all all references in a database link.

**I want to enter a database link and get all references.In react-native.**

I tried those funtions in the link below but couldn't get them work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP <3
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote "/" to ref and I got all the things.

```html
      
      const firebaseMain = firebase
      .app()
      .database('https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/')
      .ref('/');
      
      console.log("CHILDREN:");
      firebaseMain.ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
        firebaseReferences=snapshot.val();
        console.log("\x1b[32m","references: --> TYPE"+typeof firebaseReferences );
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :-

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Frist Child").child("Second Child");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I found just befor you wrote. Thank you.